# i have any error to display data from database into session variables in codeignetir as am new its pretty hard for me

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

controller

```
$session_data = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'loggedin' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
$data1['user'] = $this->Home_m->user($data);//method home_m //function user
$abc = array(
'username' => $user->username,
'date' => $user->last_login
);
$this->session->set_userdata($abc);
var_dump($this->session->set_userdata($abc));exit();
 $this->load->view('user/profile',$data);
```

model

```
  //function user
   $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where($condition);
     $this->db->or_where($cond);
        $this->db->limit(1);
   $query = $this->db->get('users');
   if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
   {
   return $query->row();
    }
```

view/profile

```
   <li><i class="fa fa-user fa-li"></i><a href="#"><?php echo $user-
    >username; ?></a></li>//here i want to display username 
                <li>BrainiMac Level<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-li"></i>
                    <a href="#B"> </a>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-li"></i><?php echo $user-
        >last_login; ?></li> //here i want to display date
```

i am retrieving data from database and want to use session variables to show this data in view . as i am new to this framework so am stuck here and dont know how to perform this. and also please review my code as i am making any mistake and ?and how to correct that .thanks in advance

Comment: update your question and mention **method** name and **filename** also.

Comment: ok i did that changes you want

Comment: how you get `$condition` variable in model's method?

Comment: as you see $data  when am calling  method .. this generates $condition variable. it is fine. just problem is how to store values that reutr from return $query-$row; into session and use this seesion on view/profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this help

```
$session_data = array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'loggedin' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
//put condition in $condition variable
$user=$this->Home_m->user($condition);
if($user){
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $abc = array(
        'username' => $user->username,
        'date' => $user->last_login
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($abc);
    $this->session->set_userdata($abc);
    $this->load->view('user/profile',$data);
}else{
    echo "user not found";
}
```

model

```
//function user
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->or_where($cond);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    return $query->row();
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it returns null

Comment: are you replace `$data` variable by `$condition` before using in `$user=$this->Home_m->user($condition);`